# Loading data into an array via an asynchronous call issues (Geofire, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, tableview, geofire

I have used the Firebase location module Geofire to searchQuery some locations near me. The query populates an array which then should be displayed onto a table (via a table reload). Unfortunately the array isn't loaded with data (count = 0) by the time the tableview reloads.
I am using the asynchronous callback (specifically the one baked into Geofire that is supposed to fire after the entire query is complete) but despite what I have read regarding the function I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Any suggestions on how I can make this work smoothly without adding a timer to delay my reload table code?

Here is some sample code:

```
var keyArray = [String]()
let query = geoFireSearchQuery(someLocation)

query.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

    keyArray.append(key)

})

query.observeReadyWithBlock({

    self.tableView.reloadData()                

    self.geofireRef.removeAllObservers()

})
```

I tried working through possible reasons and using various tests I now know that the problem here is the data isn't loading into the array fast enough- I thought using this asynchronous load would work but I feel I am missing something (still learning).

**SOLVED:**
This was an inherently BAD question and should be an example of how to not ask question on StackOverlow. I didn't want to bog it down with the details and that was a mistake. Thank you everyone for your input despite lack of information.

The problem I was having was that my array was created like this:
Query large data set, run calculations on data, store in large object, store in array, then *sort array of large objects*. Heavy computations.

My hacky solution was to use keys.count as a counter of how many objects would be in the final (large) array for any given query.
Then I set up a "did Set" variable that fires every time the large array is added to. In the did Set block I wrote a simple if statement;

```
static var bigArray = [HugeObjects]() {
        didSet {
            if self.bigArray.count == self.keys.count {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
```

The downside is that the didSet will fire every single time an object is added to the array (capped at 30 though) but I don't know how much this will effect performance. However the solution works because the tableView now reloads after the bigArray is fully written to and sorted.

Apologies for the bad question.

Comment: call tableView.reloadData inside .KeyEntered maybe ?

Comment: Calling tableView.reloadData in KeyEntered doesn't work either. I have tried a great many combinations but I think I'm missing some fundamental technique or knowledge.

Comment: is your tableView nil ? you should add debug logs in numberOfRows method

Comment: The tableView cells are populated by whatever information is in the array. The tableView is nil for about a second but will load manually. When I used a larger dataset the tableView was nil for 2-3 seconds before loading (as I spam the manual load button). I think the callback fires when the data is downloaded but not populated into the array.

Comment: You seem to be not giving any specific problem to help you with. Most of the terms is what you think is happening or what you seem to be lacking. To help you, we need you to come up with specific results. Add logs in pretty much every method to understand what is happening

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'm going to delete this question as my problem was too generic and didn't include the elements of complexity I'm facing that is most likely the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `self.geofireRef.removeAllObservers()` is the culprit. If you remove the observer, `observeReadyWithBlock` will never be called. You should not do

```
self.geofireRef.removeAllObservers()
```

within `observeEventType`

Comment: It didn't work (I retried it but I had tried it earlier too) - I have edited the question now for clarity.

Comment: is query.observeEventType callback getting called?

Comment: Yes, I used a print test to check. Is it possible that the array is too large and it is taking a significant amount of computation? The callback fires when the data is loaded from Firebase I suspect since the array is nil for a second or two.

Comment: tried removing `self.geofireRef.removeAllObservers() ` entirely?. There is a chance `query.observeReadyWithBlock` can be called multiple times and if you remove it in first place it wont work

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that I have also removed it entirely while testing and still seem to be having the problem.